# Passing a sequence of the same form? - Django

Tags: python, html, django, http, forms

the user needs to provide a list of field/values through a form

```
class FieldForm(forms.Form):

    field_name = forms.CharField()
    field_value = forms.CharField()
```

The problem is how do I get a user to **pass multiple of these with one submit**?

---

Also as a side question... any tips on implementing editing too?

---

Any ideas? **It would be really great to get your feedback!** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/formsets/) are what you are after.